# How to install packages in specific installation of Python?

Tags: python

I am using Python with Power BI. For this, it is recommended to install Python 3.7 without anaconda.

I would usually use anaconda prompt to install packages, but how can I install packages here? I know the path to my specific python installation which is `"C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37"`.

How can I install packages specifically for this installation? Using pip is fine, but im not sure how to reference this installation in the command prompt

Comment: `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python -m pip install ...`

Comment: Other than simplicity, not clear why Anaconda's distribution couldn't be used.